# Pending constant setting in React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

my hook:

```
export function useToken2() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'authenticated' && session?.accessToken) {
      logger('useEffect setToken')
      setToken(session.accessToken);

    }
  }, [status, session]);

  const tokenFn = useCallback(async (): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
      if (token != null) {
        resolve(token);
      } else {
        const tokenInterval = setInterval(() => {
          if (token != null) {
            clearInterval(tokenInterval);
            resolve(token);
          }
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(() => {
          clearInterval(tokenInterval);
          logger('tokenFn timeout')
          resolve('');
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
  }, [token]);

  return {
    tokenFn,
  };
}
```

hook call:

```
const Test: FC = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const {tokenFn} = useToken2()

  useEffect(() => {
    tokenFn().then((res) => {
      setToken(res)
    })
  }, []);

  return (
      <>
        {token}
      </>
  );
};
```

The token is always empty, but hook cannot return null as token.
status === 'authenticated' is set some time after start.
How to expect token setting in tokenFn? setInterval doesn't work.
Log:

- useEffect setToken
- tokenFn timeout

Comment: does the if block in useEffect of hook ever gets executed? if no, your state will never be updated, try changing that condition

Comment: yes, useEffect set token

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
import {useSession} from 'next-auth/react';
import {useQuery} from "react-query";

export function useToken2() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const { data: token } = useQuery(["token"], async () =>
  { return  session?.accessToken ?? ""}, {enabled: !!session?.accessToken && status === "authenticated"});
  
  return {
   token
  };
}
```